# passport.js 'user' is undefined when sucessRedirect

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Please, I'm trying to redirect to the "edit user route" page after login but the `req.user._id` is showing undefined, any idea what's wrong here?

**login router**

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect:'../profiles/edit/' + req.user._id, <<<< **UNDEFINED**
        failureRedirect:'./login',
        failureFlash: true,
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

**passport.js**

```
module.exports = function(passport) {
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  },
  (username, password, done) => {
    Profile.findOne({
      username:username
    }).then(user => {
      if(!user) {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'No user found'});
      }
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (isMatch) {
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Password Incorrect'});
        }
      })
    })
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  Profile.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});    
}
```

**app.js**

```
app.use(session({
secret: 'secret',
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true,
  }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

I'm getting:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can't get user details in the authenticate method, it will check if username has been found and then pass it to the next middleware

```
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
         // here you can access user info
         res.redirect('../profiles/edit/' + req.user._id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand :)

Comment: Glad it helps, if my answer works for you, You can accept it as your best answer, you can also read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page to know how stackoverflow works :°)